What is the action-cost of grabbing spell components?
Context
In terms of Actions, Bonus Actions, Free interaction and "Part of the Action", what are the rules for grabbing spell components needed when casting a spell in the new 2024 5e ruleset.
The relevant rules I found are:

Interacting with Things. You can interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe.


When time is short, such as in combat, interactions with objects are limited: one free interaction per turn. That interaction must occur during a creature’s movement or action. Any additional interactions require the Utilize action, as explained in “Combat” later in this chapter.


A Material component is a particular material used in a spell’s casting, as specified in parentheses in the Components entry. These materials aren’t consumed by the spell unless the spell’s description states otherwise. The spellcaster must have a hand free to access them, but it can be the same hand used to perform Somatic components, if any.


If a spell doesn’t consume its materials and doesn’t specify a cost for them, a spellcaster can use a Component Pouch (see chapter 6) instead of providing the materials specified in the spell, or the spellcaster can substitute a Spellcasting Focus if the caster has a feature that allows that substitution. To use a Component Pouch, you must have a hand free to reach into it, and to use a Spellcasting Focus, you must hold it unless its description says otherwise (see chapter 6 for descriptions).

As a hypothetical (as I could not find such a spell, but the rules don't exclude them) we have a spell with material components: 1 diamond (50gp) and a small bit of yarn.
Our wizard with nothing in his hands wants to cast this spell.
Question
As what are the following classified

Reaching into his component pouch.
Grabbing the diamond of his belt.
Grabbing a bit of yarn from his belt.
Grabbing his spell focus.

(Not all of them are needed for one spell, but each could be used)
Action, Free Interaction, "Part of casting the Spell"?

Where does it say you grab the components?
The only requirements are that you have them and that you have a “have a hand free to access them”. Or that you have a component pouch and a hand free to reach into it, or are holding a focus. Don’t read in words like “grab” that aren’t there.
On a strict reading, merely being able to access them is enough, it never says that you actually do access them. Perhaps the magical forces transfer the essence of the components to your hand.
A more prosaic reading is that you do access them, but that merely means you have to touch them, not grab them or anything else. Although read the spell, it may say you do something specific with the components.
It’s part of the action
It says it right in the bit about components:

A Material component is … used in a spell’s casting

And the action is being used to cast the spell.

I agree with your reasoning, whilst "used in a spell’s casting" is still ambiguous if it means "as part of" or "is needed for". The rules as they are written seem to indicate that the most important aspect is simply having them and having a free hand.
But you don't address the spell focus part, I don't think RAW give the same "part of" properties to a spell focus.

Aren't you a lawyer in the IRL world? :-) I think here we deal not only with rules as written, but also with common concepts. The common concept about the usage of material components is that the caster grabs them and uses them. That is supported also by the rule that (if the opposite is not written) then a material component can be used only once, it is rendered unusable by the casting. But I admit that d&d5 has a very clear only-as-written rule, making your argumentation at least considerable if not even acceptable. Btw, now I think d&d5 RaW rule is bad.

@GraySheep I can’t commit to the 2024 rules, but the default in the current rules is that material components are not consumed.

@DaleM Wow, thanks!

Accessing the required material components is part of the Magic action to cast the spell
The answer is the same for most of your scenarios: you access the components as part of the Magic action, bonus action or reaction used to cast the spell.
One reason for this is the existence of spells with a casting time of 1 Action and more than one material component, e.g. Bigby’s Hand, Fireball and Heat Metal.
For it to be possible to cast those spells, all the required components - including verbal and somatic ones - must be supplied as part of the Magic action used to cast them. Otherwise, even using the single free object interaction, more than one material component could not be used.
An alternative might be to count accessing the Component Pouch as a single object interaction even for multiple material components. I don’t think that interpretation works though, because it would prevent the casting of two or more spells per turn. We know this is possible, since the rules describe multiple ways that a spell may be cast without a spell slot, and then state under Casting Time:

One Spell with a Spell Slot per Turn
On a turn, you can expend only one spell slot to cast a spell.

Spells with material components include cantrips (e.g. Dancing Lights or Shillelagh), and spells with casting times of 1 Bonus Action (Barkskin or Hex) and 1 Reaction (Feather Fall). So to make it possible to cast two of those on a turn, material components or using a Focus must be part of the action of casting each spell.
For narrative justification of this - and perhaps evidence that this is the intent of the rules - see the description of the component pouch. As in the 2014 version, it goes out of its way to explain how it makes accessing a specific component easy:

A Component Pouch is watertight and filled with compartments that hold all the free Material components of your spells.

Grabbing a Spellcasting Focus not already in hand would either also be part of the action, or count as a free object interaction
The rules for using a Spellcasting Focus say “you must hold it unless its description says otherwise”. Your wizard is not already holding their Focus, and none of the Arcane Focuses make such an exception. I see two ways to rule this.
The obvious one would be to have the character draw the Focus from wherever it’s stowed during their Magic action (or beforehand during their move) as a free object interaction.
But it’d also be reasonable to say this is  part of the Magic action too. The rules don’t explicitly allow it, but it’s analogous to the new rules around equipping and unequipping weapons as part of an attack - which might also support the intent of the components rules.
From the rules glossary entry for “Attack [Action]”:

Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can either equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. You do so either before or after the attack. If you equip a weapon before an attack, you don’t need to use it for that attack. Equipping a weapon includes drawing it from a sheath or picking it up. Unequipping a weapon includes sheathing, stowing, or dropping it.

